# Configuring eclipse to use jad

Tags: eclipse, jad

- I [downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) the jar file and placed it into plugins dir
- I [downloaded](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) the binary and placed it into some other dir
- I bounced eclipse (Juno - Version: 4.2.0)
- I updated the jadclipse to point to the correct folder
  [image]

When clicking on a method that exists in a jar whose source i don't have, decompilation does not happen.

**Did i miss something?**

Comment: You can simply install the JadClipse plugin via the Eclipse update site : http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/update/ (See [Jad's documentation](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) )

Comment: I have written the ans here please follow the link
:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45995421/3454208

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you change the default editor for class files as stated in the JadClipse wiki?

> The Eclipse Class File Viewer instead of the JadClipse Class File Viewer is opened.
>   Go to Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations and make sure that the JadClipse Class File Viewer has the default file association for *.class files.

For more recent releases of Eclipse, also make sure that '*.class without source' is set to use JadClipse Class File Viewer by default.  Installing the plugin will only set the '*.class' only by default.

Comment: @Jam, you should write as a separate answer or modify the one above.  The '.class without source' was the change I had to make too.  The answer above does not mention it.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations and select *.class without source* and remove *Class File Viewer* if it is already there by default and keep only JadClipse Class File Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

In Kepler, Window-> Eclipse marketplace. Install Jad. Restart. Go to Window-> Install software, and paste http://feeling.sourceforge.net/update. Select both, and install. Should work now...

Answer (score 0):

Integrated Java Decompiler (Jad) with Eclipse

**1. Download Jad**

Download the Jad executable file.

> Official Jad website seem not working any more, try mirror download
> links instead. Jad Official website http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html Jad
> mirror download
>
> http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JAD.shtml
> http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

**2. Download Jad Eclipse plugin**

Download the Jad Eclipse plugin named `Jabclipse (net.sf.jadclipse_x.x.x.jar)`
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/

**3. Copy it to Eclipse plugin folder**

Copy the downloaded Jad Eclipse plugin – `Jabclipse(jadclipse_x.x.x.jar)` to Eclipse plugin folder.
For example,

> D:\eclipse\plugins\net.sf.jadclipse_3.3.0.jar

P.S No need to extract it, just copy the whole jar file.

**4. Restart Eclipse**

Restart Eclipse to make the plugin take effect.

**5. Configure Jadclipse in Eclipse**

In Eclipse, Click Window –> Preference –> Java –> Jadclipse , Key in Jad’s path in “Path to Decompiler” field

[image]

**6. Done**

In Eclipse, try F3 into any class which does not has the source, Jad will decompile it automatically.

see examples :

```
/*jadclipse*/// Decompiled by Jad v1.5.8f. Copyright 2001 Pavel Kouznetsov.
// Jad home page: http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) radix(10) lradix(10)
// Source File Name:   JSObject.java

package netscape.javascript;

import java.applet.Applet;
import sun.plugin.javascript.JSContext;

// Referenced classes of package netscape.javascript:
//            JSException

public abstract class JSObject
{
```

Reference :  https://mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/